# Correct redirect (header redirect) and change the language on the site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have some issues while developing my site. I want to realize multilanguage web site, but i don't know how to make correct redirecting for visitors.
For example, the user has come to my web site `http://web-site.com/ua/` he sees the default language, and when he walk around through the site he needed to change to english language `http://web-site.com/en/`.

And now is the problem, how should i realize the next, when he is on product page or other, for example now is:
`http://web-site.com/ua/automotive/wheels/product_url`
and he is changing language, so now url would be look like this:
`http://web-site.com/en/automotive/wheels/product_url`
But i don't know how to make the redirect for the same url but with `/en/` instead of `/ua/`. Can some one help me? Or what solutions would be better.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or maybe it would be better make some redirects in `.htaccess` from `http://web-site.com/` to `http://web-site.com/en/`. But this is another question.

I did my own router, not like the usual MVC routers, but very similar. If necessary, i will add it below at this question.

Comment: If the user is "choosing" to switch languages, this is not done with a redirect, it is just a link.  He clicks "English" and that link has the new url in it.

Comment: You should store the language in a session/database and render the proper language or view depending on that value. Don't pass state around in the URL like that.

Comment: You should look at the google translate api and see how you can integrate it into your project.